# How to log inputs into a function inside a package in python

Tags: python, logging

While using profiler to look for the location where most of the execution time is spent in my  python code, i found that it is from a package used in the code. So a function in a package is called 100s of times with different input arguments. In total this function takes the maximum time to execute.

So I want to implement some caching, so that if same parameters are passed, I can use the already extracted output from cache. So first I want to check if same parameters are being passed multiple times at all.

Is there any way I can enable some python level configuration, so that I can get arguments passed to the function on each iteration?

As I am not allowed to make any changes to this package `Package1`. So enabling something outside (like enabling `debug` mode) the pakage only may help.

```
Package1
    module1
        def function1()
           for i in range(10000):
              
              ###Want to get arguments passed
              ###for each iteration of below function to a logfile

              retvalue = function2(ar1,arg2,arg3) 



My Code
    package1.module1.function1()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) from python to cache the values.

```py
from functools import cache

@cache
def function2(*args):
    return function1(*args) # function1 imported from module you can't change
```

Instead of logging the input args, you can use profiler to see if the runtime has improved. If it has, you can be sure that some calls are duplicate.